# UINavigationController push to a different UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this that I am obviously missing.

I have three classes in my UINavigation Controller:

1. MasterNavViewController - of type UINavigationController - owns the properties across all the subsequent view controllers.
2. FirstNavViewController - of type UIViewController.
3. SecondNavViewController - of type UIViewController.

For reasons of threading that I don't want to go into here I would like to move from the FirstNavViewController to the SecondNavViewController using code. I have tried:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:SecondNavViewController animated:YES];
```

but I am getting an error in my code: Use of undeclared identifier 'SecondNavViewController' did you mean MasterNavViewController?

I'm not exactly sure how to proceed with this. I have tried importing my SecondNavViewController.h but that doesn't seem to work either.

I'm thinking perhaps I am trying to do this the wrong way. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! James

As Requested:
I'm not creating the SecondNavViewController explicitly in the code, I'm not sure how... but that's where I'm going wrong most likely right?. I have created the classes & then linked them with the UIViewController that I dragged into IB. Typically I would just create a push segue between the two but in this case I do not want to do that.

Comment: How are you creating SecondNavViewController object? Post that code as well.

Comment: You need to pass a variable that is referencing an instance of the view controller you want to display, not the name of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SecondNavViewController` is not equal to `secondNavViewController`. Objective-C is case sensitive.

So you need to SecondNavViewController instance like:

```
SecondNavViewController * secondNavViewController = [[SecondNavViewController alloc] ...];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondNavViewController animated:YES];
...
```

Comment: Thanks @Kjuly !
Using this code:
`SecondNavViewController *navcontroller = [[SecondNavViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:navcontroller animated:YES];`
The view is now pushed correctly to the SecondNavViewController UIViewController class however it is loading with a black background. Is this because the view isn't loading correctly (perhaps it needs to be passed to the object when initialising from FirstNavViewController?) After some googling I modified the viewLoad & viewDidLoad methods but nothing seemed to work. Any more help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: @JamesLCQ if you've created your view without Interface Builder, you need to implement `-loadView` method, where self.view is created.

Comment: I created the UIViewController in IB (i.e. dragged the object in & modified it's appearance but I am just calling it from within code. Does your statement regarding `loadView` still apply? If so, I have put [super self.view] into the `loadView` method but to no avail. What exactly should I be putting in the method? Thanks!

Comment: @JamesLCQ if you did it via IB, you don't need to overwrite `-loadView`. Try to put `[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];` into `-(void)viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I changed the background color as described in your comment which works fine. However all of the content I created in IB (UIButtons, etc) are not appearing at all when my SecondNavViewController is loading. Any other ideas?

Current in viewDidLoad I just have: 
`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}`

Comment: @JamesLCQ have you tried to put `[super viewDidLoad];` in front? And b.t.w, every subview should be added to `self.view`.

Comment: thanks for your ongoing support! :) Could you please give me a code example that shows how to add the subviews to my self.view?

Comment: @JamesLCQ `yourSubviewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; [self.view addSubview:subviewController.view];` I suggest you to learn more on UIKit first. :)

Comment: Agreed, I am still learning the ropes with this :$ Attempting to learn by doing. One additional question before I test again this evening if I may:
Currently I am initialising my SecondNavController in my FirstNavController.m class & then pushing to it from that class. Should your code above for adding the subviews come in the FirstNavController after init of the object or in the SecondNavController in the viewDidLoad method? Thanks!

Comment: @JamesLCQ `yourSubviewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourSubviewController animated:YES];`

Comment: I am still unable to get past this issue. I will create a new question & upload my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a UIViewController in interface builder and initializing and displaying it programmatically then you must create an instance of your class using `-initWithNibName:bundle:` and them pass that to `-pushViewController:animated:` rather than the class name.

As you are doing this for threading reasons you must be careful to do all updating of the UI including pushing a new view controller on the main thread. this can be easily done as follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
{
    // update ui or push view controller etc.
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel like I'm getting somewhere with this now. I'm not sure how to create the instance within -initWithNibName:bundle: could you provide some sample code for that?

As a test I added the SecondNavViewController to the .h & synthesized it. The code compiled but I got an error when executing the method:

Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <MasterNavViewController: 0x9665940>. Which seemed to point the wrong ViewContoller...

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial on setting up a viewcontoller from a Nib file, it's a little out of date as it uses Xcode 3.x rather than xcode 4 but the concept is exactly the same... You design the view controller in a nib/xib file, connect the outlets and then use -initWithNibName:bundle: to create an instance that you can programatically show.

Comment: Thanks! I don't see any link in your post. Did you include it?